# XPath: Match one of multiple children

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a small application that searches publication citations. The citations are in XML and I pass parameters to XSLT through PHP to search by fields like instrument or author. The structure looks like this:

```
<publications>
    <paper>
        <authors>
            <author>James Smith</author>
            <author>Jane Doe</author>
        </authors>
        <year>2010</year>
        <title>Paper 1</title>
        (more children)
    </paper>
    (more papers)
</publications>
```

When I call my template in the XSLT, I use a predicate to pare down which papers are shown based on the search criteria. So if the parameter $author is set, for example, I do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="paper[contains(authors/author, $author)]" />
```

The problem: this works for the *first* author in "authors", but ignores the ones after that. So in the example above, searching for "Smith" would return this paper, but "Doe" returns nothing.

How can I format my expression to take **all** "author" elements into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `contains` function expects a string as its first argument, not a set of nodes. With your expression the first result of `authors/author` is converted to a string and then passed to the function.

Instead, use a predicate that tests each of the `author` nodes independently:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="paper[authors/author[contains(., $author)]]" />
```

See, for example, this explanation of Saxon's behavior:

- http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html#StringExpressions

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a dream.